# Android order sqlite table with capitalized and non-capitalized first letter

Tags: android, sqlite

I query certain tables of an sqlite database:

```
public Cursor showAllTables(){
        String mySql = " SELECT name FROM sqlite_master " + " WHERE type='table'             "
                + "   AND name LIKE 'PR_%' ORDER BY name";
        return ourDatabase.rawQuery(mySql, null);
    }
```

I get this result:

- Chevrolet
- Ferrari
- Maserati
- bugatti
- hyundai

How can I have the list ordered independently of the first letter being capital or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add `COLLATE NOCASE` to the end of your query:

```
public Cursor showAllTables(){
        String mySql = " SELECT name FROM sqlite_master " + " WHERE type='table'             "
                + "   AND name LIKE 'PR_%' ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE";
        return ourDatabase.rawQuery(mySql, null);
    }
```

Or you could recreate the table and add `COLLATE NOCASE` to the column definition.

Comment: Glad to help erdomester. I've heard recreating the table and updating the column definition will give you a performance increase though this is second hand information I've had no noticeable differences myself.

Comment: Hm. It would be good know what performance increase can I get over how many tables/records. I am using only a couple of tables with a couple of records, so in my case I don't think we can talk about performance increase, but what you suggested may be important in case of bigger databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
public Cursor showAllTables(){
    String mySql = " SELECT name FROM sqlite_master " + " WHERE type='table'             "
                    + "   AND name LIKE 'PR_%' ORDER BY lower(name)";
    return ourDatabase.rawQuery(mySql, null);
}
```

I changed only name with lower(name).

Comment: This is also a good solution, but you were late 26 seconds :S Thank you!